# BizTalk - SFTP - Overwrite Existing file

Tags: biztalk

I am trying to copy a file using SFTP .

Suppose in the destination SFTP location same file name exists, can we overwrite that with a new file?

Or can we delete the existing file in the destination and copy the new one?

We know the file name which needs to be moved to destination SFTP location.

Comment: From the SFTP tag: `GENERAL SFTP SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. SSH File Transfer Protocol, a network protocol designed to provide secure file transfer and manipulation facilities over SSH (Secure Shell protocol).`

Comment: @Alex, if he is asking about configuring the BizTalk SFTP adapter, then it is not of topic.

Comment: bigB are you using the out of the box BizTalk SFTP adapter, or a third party one?  What version of BizTalk are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the SFTP adapter, the default behavior is to overwrite if it already exists. It's probably best to try it out yourself, because you will have questions about how components behave more often in BizTalk.